# Can't understand simple Netlogo error

Tags: netlogo

```
show sort-on [who] [turtles]
```

**gives error**

*Expected an agentset here, rather than a list or block.*

I can't understand the error turtles is an agenset isn't it? I have copied it from Netlogo dictionary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the square brackets from around `turtles`. `turtles` on its own is the agent set containing all turtles. Putting square brackets around stuff either makes it a list or command/reporter block.

The error is saying that `sort-on` wants an agent set for one of its arguments, but you've given it a something that could be a list or block.